# slide view from top

Tags: ios, button, view

Does anyone know how I can click on a button and display a panel from the top?

Similar to the way YouTube app displays the search bar once you click on the search button.

Not sure how to slide a view in from the top and display over a view.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to give some more information than that. How do you want the menu to slide down? If its with a gesture, I personally would avoid this type of UI, since Apple has the Notification Centre that comes down with a slide from the top - so this could conflict with your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did something like this and it seems to work but isn't as smooth as I expect on first launch after a couple of clicks starts to work

```
if (showBanner == false) {

     showBanner = true;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);
    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(267,101, 47, 30);

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
else{

     showBanner = false;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -100, 320, 100);
    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(262, 20, 47, 30);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work for the first couple of click?

Answer (score 0):

In your view did load set the sliding view's origin y value to something negative (so that its just off the top of the screen).

Then when you want it to appear set the y value to 0, you can do this with animation using UIView:animateWithDuration.

One its appeared if you wanted you could add a pan gesture recognizer so the user can swipe it back up, or you can trigger it moving back up programatically.